# Change how PSQL shows queries

Tags: postgresql, psql

This is a minor issue, but it's driving me nuts.

Anyways, on some of my servers I'm running PostgreSQL 8.4.  When using PSQL (also 8.4), queries are shown with a less-like interface, which I'm quite happy with.

However, on my newer servers I'm running PostgreSQL 9.3, and PSQL (also 9.3) has slightly changed up how it views the queries:  Similar less-like interface, but when I hit `q` to exit **it clears the results from the screen**.  This drives me nuts; I often will run a `SELECT` query and use the results to write an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` query, which is made much more difficult when I can't see the results while I'm writing the query.

Is there any way I can change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is behaviour of your pager, not PostgreSQL or `psql`.

You can tell `psql` not to use a pager at all with:

```
\pset pager off
```

(this can go in your `.psqlrc` to make it persistent). That'll potentially result in long, uncontrollable scrolling results though.

To instead tell the pager `less`, which I'm guessing is your default, not to clear the screen, [see this related answer](https://serverfault.com/q/567017/102814).

Comment: Great, `export PAGER="less -X"` worked perfectly.